# decrypting jabber requests

Tags: xmpp, wireshark

I'm having some with a small test network setup with a jabberd server and two IM clients connected to it. I wanna try and use wireshark to sniff data from the sender side and analyze the xml being sent.

Im only interested in the "requests" of the side "sending" the file. Im able to use the jabber.request filter on wireshark to look at the request; however, it looks encrypted. The test server is mine, so I believe that I should be able to decrypt it too.

Could someone offer some guidance on how I could go about doing that?

**[EDIT]**
I just noticed that I have disabled SSL/TLS on my machine; hence the message could not be encrypted - but is still in a weird format. Please find attached, a screenshot.

[image]

**[EDIT 2]**
The data being sent is

`"Request: \027\003\001\000 t:\202UZ\367\354\360\307\aT,\211\a\241\346\a\223YYe9\005\023\204U\377\376\323\002\322\322"`

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Spark and press F-12](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1325) to enable the Smack debug window.  It will show you all incoming and outgoing packets in a self contained window.  You can view them in a table format or raw XML.